# DBT bigquery connection issue

Tags: google-bigquery, service-accounts, dbt, google-iam

I connected bigquery with DBT using service account with owner permission. Things were going good. After a while the command `dbt debug` gives me this error:

```
17:45:59  Connection:
17:45:59    method: service-account
17:45:59    database: dbt-practice-project-409015
17:45:59    execution_project: dbt-practice-project-409015
17:45:59    schema: customers_dataset
17:45:59    location: US
17:45:59    priority: interactive
17:45:59    maximum_bytes_billed: None
17:45:59    impersonate_service_account: None
17:45:59    job_retry_deadline_seconds: None
17:45:59    job_retries: 1
17:45:59    job_creation_timeout_seconds: None
17:45:59    job_execution_timeout_seconds: 300
17:45:59    keyfile: /path/to/file.json
17:45:59    timeout_seconds: 300
17:45:59    refresh_token: None
17:45:59    client_id: None
17:45:59    token_uri: None
17:45:59    dataproc_region: None
17:45:59    dataproc_cluster_name: None
17:45:59    gcs_bucket: None
17:45:59    dataproc_batch: None
17:45:59  Registered adapter: bigquery=1.7.2
17:45:59    Connection test: [ERROR]

17:45:59  1 check failed:
17:45:59  dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

  >Runtime Error
  Unable to generate access token, if you're using impersonate_service_account, make sure your initial account has the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role on the account you are trying to impersonate.

  ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.'})

Check your database credentials and try again. For more information, visit:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configure-your-profile
```

I even tried adding new service account with owner permission and generated json and pointed to keyfile in config. Still the issue persists. How can I fix this?

Comment: try to add a TokenCreator role to your service account and run it again

Comment: Can you add your profiles.yml file in the post above?